# How to get Maven 3.0.4 to use Java7?

Tags: java, maven, maven-3, osx-mountain-lion

I've just updated maven from 3.0.3 to 3.0.4 using the compiled binaries from the official site.Now when I run mvn -version , it says that it uses the old java 6 version , instead of the java 7 version that I have installed on my machine (macbook pro).
If I run the 3.0.3 version maven binary from inside its folder it uses the java 7 version.
How can I configure maven 3.0.4 so that it uses the Java 7 version?
Thank you.

PS : Java 7 is the default java version at my system (mountain lion).

Comment: So you're saying that 3.0.3 uses 1.7 and 3.0.4 doesn't? That sounds really weird since both of them should be using jdk specified in `JAVA_HOME`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set the JAVA_HOME environment variable.

Comment: I've managed to fix it using the following command :
    export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.7`(this way the variable always is set to the default java version).

Comment: You also need to add %JAVA_HOME%/bin in the PATH variable. Only JAVA_HOME is not enough.

Answer (score 6):

Set the JAVA_HOME environment variable. and path as $JAVA_HOME/bin

From Apache maven:

Unix-based Operating Systems (Linux, Solaris and Mac OS X)

Extract the distribution archive, i.e. apache-maven-3.0.4-bin.tar.gz to the directory you wish to install Maven 3.0.4. These instructions assume you chose /usr/local/apache-maven. The subdirectory apache-maven-3.0.4 will be created from the archive.
In a command terminal,

add the M2_HOME environment variable, e.g. `export M2_HOME=/usr/local/apache-maven/apache-maven-3.0.4.`

Add the M2 environment variable, e.g. `export M2=$M2_HOME/bin`.

Optional: Add the MAVEN_OPTS environment variable to specify JVM properties, e.g. `export MAVEN_OPTS="-Xms256m -Xmx512m".` This environment variable can be used to supply extra options to Maven.

Add M2 environment variable to your path, e.g. `export PATH=$M2:$PATH.`

Make sure that JAVA_HOME is set to the location of your JDK, e.g. `export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.7.*` and that `$JAVA_HOME/bin` is in your PATH environment variable.

Run mvn --version to verify that it is correctly installed.

Answer (score 2):

setting the JAVA_HOME variable would usually do the trick, although that was the case in previous versions of Maven as well. Still worth checking if the variable is set (and pointing to the desired version of Java).

EDIT: fixing grammar